# Django: Distinct on forgin key relationship

Tags: django, distinct, django-queryset

I'm working on a Ticket/Issue-tracker in django where I need to log the status of each ticket. This is a simplification of my models.

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    assigned_to = ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.TextField(_('comment'), blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_("created at"), auto_now_add=True)

class TicketStatus(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (10, _('Open'),),
        (20, _('Other'),),
        (30, _('Closed'),),
    )

    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, verbose_name=_('ticket'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'))
    status = models.IntegerField(_('status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    date = models.DateTimeField(_("created at"), auto_now_add=True)
```

Now, getting the status of a ticket is easy sorting by date and retrieving the first column like this.

```
ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=1)
ticket.ticketstatus_set.order_by('-date')[0].get_status_display()
```

But then I also want to be able to filter on status in the Admin, and those have to get the status trough a Ticket-queryset, which makes it suddenly more complex. How would I get a queryset with all Tickets with a certain status?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "get the status through a Ticket-queryset"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to avoid a cycle (asking for each ticket status) to filter manually the queryset. As far as I know you cannot avoid that cycle. Here are ideas:

```
# select_related avoids a lot of hits in the database when enter the cycle
t_status = TicketStatus.objects.select_related('Ticket').filter(status = ID_STATUS)
# this is an array with the result
ticket_array = [ts.ticket for ts in tickets_status]
```

Or, since you mention you were looking for a QuerySet, this might be what you are looking for

```
# select_related avoids a lot of hits in the database when enter the cycle
t_status = TicketStatus.objects.select_related('Ticket').filter(status = ID_STATUS)
# this is a QuerySet with the result
tickets = Tickets.objects.filter(pk__in = [ts.ticket.pk for ts in t_status])
```

However, the problem might be in the way you are modeling the data. What you called TickedStatus is more like TicketStatusLog because you want to keep track of the user and date who change the status.

Therefore, the reasonable approach is to add a field 'current_status' to the Ticket model that is updated each time a new TicketStatus is created. In this way (1) you don't have to order a table each time you ask for a ticket and (2) you would simply do something like Ticket.objects.filter(current_status = ID_STATUS) for what I think you are asking.